# Messages not reaching destination queue when using ServerInitializerFactory Netty 4

Tags: grails, apache-camel, activemq-classic, netty

I am using apache camel netty4 in grails and I have declared mycustom ServerInitializerFactory as follows

```
public class MyServerInitializerFactory extends ServerInitializerFactory {
    private int maxLineSize = 1048576;
    NettyConsumer nettyConsumer

    public MimacsServerInitializerFactory() {}

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline()
        pipeline.addLast("logger", new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
        pipeline.addLast("framer", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN, maxLineSize, 2, 2, 6, 0, false))
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MfuDecoder())
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MfuEncoder())
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new MyServerHandler())
    }
}
```

I have a route which I setup as follows in my routebuilder.

```
from('netty4:tcp://192.168.254.3:553?serverInitializerFactory=#sif&keepAlive=true&sync=true&allowDefaultCodec=false').to('activemq:queue:Tracking.Queue')
```

My Camel Context is setup in the BootStrap.groovy as follows

```
def serverInitializerFactory = new MyServerInitializerFactory()
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry()
registry.put("sif", serverInitializerFactory)

CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(registry)
camelContext.addComponent("activemq",  activeMQComponent.activeMQComponent("failover:tcp://localhost:61616"))
camelContext.addRoutes new TrackingMessageRoute()
camelContext.start()
```

When I run my app, my route is started and my framer, decoder, handler and encoders are all invoked but messages do not reach the Tracking. Queue and responses do not get back to the client.

If I do not use `serverInitializerFactory` in the netty url and user encoders and decoders instead, My messages are hitting the queue but I lose control of the acknowledgement that I want to sent for each type of message that I receive. It seems `activemq` tries to sent its own response which is rejected by my encoder.

Am I supposed to then write code to send again or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around that problem. In my channelRead0 method. I added the following lines

```
Exchange exchange = this.consumer.getEndpoint().createExchange(ctx, msg);
```

where ctx is the ChannelContextHandler and msg is the Message Object, the two are both parameters of the channelRead0 method.

I also added the following lines

```
this.consumer.createUoW(exchange);
```

and after my handling code I inserted the following line

```
this.consumer.doneUoW(exchange);
```

and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a handler with the consumer so it can be routed, see the unit test how its done:

- https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-netty4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/netty4/NettyCustomPipelineFactoryAsynchTest.java#L112

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have a handler like the one if u check on the code snippets that I posted. Do I need code in my handler that sends messages to a queue. Are messages not supposed to just go to queue since the queue is the destination in my camel route?